# What type of fish is this- Cabo San Lucas, Gulf of California side

Tags: species-identification

[image: fish]
Can anybody tell me what this fish is?  Caught in Cabo last week, actually closer to San Jose, with a Joe's Flies 1/4oz spinner.  Cool looking fish for sure, just can't seem to find it online of what it is??

Comment: We need a picture...

Answer (score 3):

That is a giant hawkfish, Cirrhitus rivulatus. It is identified by its unique markings from other species in the same region. This individual looks slightly young to me from the size, however it is most certainly this species. [Giant hawkfish on mexican-fish.com](https://www.mexican-fish.com/giant-hawkfish/)

Comment: Cannot thank you enough!  You look to be exactly right!

Comment: @BrettNelson No problem. If you think the answer is correct you can also accept the answer but no need to.